# Circular UIImage from FBSDK xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I have a profile picture which I am taking from a URL from facebook graph request that I am trying to make into a circular profile picture but it is appearing like this:
[image: Not so circular!]

I don't want it to be pointing at the top, I just want a perfect circle.

This is my code:

```
  @IBOutlet var imageURL: UIImageView!

 func returnUserData()
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,name,picture.width(50).height(50)"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")
                let userID : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as! NSString
                let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                print("User Name is: \(userName)")
                let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                print("User Email is: \(userEmail)")

                let facebookProfileUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"

                print("\(facebookProfileUrl)")

                let url = NSURL(string:facebookProfileUrl)
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)
                if data == nil {

                } else {
                    self.imageURL.layer.borderWidth=1.0
                    self.imageURL.layer.masksToBounds = false
                    self.imageURL.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                    self.imageURL.layer.cornerRadius = 15
                    self.imageURL.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageURL.frame.size.height/2
                    self.imageURL.clipsToBounds = true
                    self.imageURL.image = UIImage(data:data!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is your UIImageView set to square like for example 50x50?

Comment: When I add
                    self.imageURL = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
it disappears

Comment: didi you add it as subview self.view.addSubview(self.imageURL). This picture will be in your top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your input image isn't square.  Crop the top and bottom  (or extend the sides) to make it square, then the rest should work.